# MySQL IF Clause in WHERE + Insert Into

Tags: mysql, if-statement, where-clause

Hi I have a dataset where I want to seperate original projects (roots) from copied projects (forked) and insert these two results into a new table.

```
INSERT INTO root_fork (root_id)
SELECT
    projects.id
FROM
    projects,
    all_projs_limit
WHERE
    projects.id = all_projs_limit.project_id 
    and projects.forked_from is NULL;
```

and the other is

```
INSERT INTO root_fork (fork_id)
SELECT
    projects.id
FROM
    projects,
    all_projs_limit
WHERE
    projects.id = all_projs_limit.project_id 
    and projects.forked_from is not NULL;
```

I want to have both as one SQL statement. Is that possible for example with if and else?

Comment: nothing of that is vaild mysql code and you can do that in a where clause. Please explain with some data what you wqant to do., because ican't figure out ´, why your insert query are supposed to do

Comment: Hey I just realised it. So I reranged the question. I hope this gets more clear now.
Both SQL-Statements are perfectly running seperatly but I want to have them as one sql-query

Comment: Show the schema and explain the meaning of `root_fork`. It's not clear why you would have a bunch of rows with only a `root_id` and then another bunch with only a `fork_id`. It sounds like they should have both, in order to relate roots to forks.

Comment: This is just a step to the next step. I am doing some data analysis and therefore I need to sepearte them both. I am currently on the run. I can post the schema later. But I really just want them to be sperated into forks and roots

Comment: What are the condition for theNULL or NOT NULL, and comma seprated tables are notused and frwned upppo, use proper joins,